# Is the a way to create a custom grouping function in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is it possible to have a custom grouping function for grouping rows. So rather than equality we could group by a fuzzy match or some other logic. The ag-grid documentation does not have anything explicitly outlined about this. Does anyone in this community know if it's possible?